# Android: cannot connect to 192.168.1.103:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

Tags: android, debugging, adb, wifi

First: There are similar questions around, but either they don't provide much information or they ask how to make the connection. This question regards a specific problem:

I have 2 computers and 2 android phones:

- Computer 1 is a laptop, running a Debian linux and connects via WiFi.
- Computer 2 is a desktop PC, running win10 and connects to the same
  network via Ethernet cable.
- Android phone 1 is a Xiaomi Redmi running android 9.
- Android phone 2 is a Huawei p30 Lite running android 9.

All 4 devices are connected to the same local network.

I did setup both phones to listen on port 5555 via a usb cable with the command:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

**From the laptop(running linux):**

I am able to connect to both phones with the command:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.10X:5555 (Where X is 2/3 for the 2 devices).
```

**From the PC(running win10):**

- I am able to connect to the Xiaomi device using the same command.
- I cannot connect to the Huawei device with the same command and I get the error:

  *cannot connect to 192.168.1.102:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)*

What can I do to fix the problem and debug via WiFi PC->Huawei?

Comment: How does one connect to device? I only know that one can connect to server apps running on a device.

Comment: When developing for android, you need to connect the computer to an android device to test your app. This is done, using the Android Debug Bridge "adb". https://developer.android.com/guide